# Input Submit Button Height Is Not Rendering As Expected

Tags: css

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input class="short" type="text" name="user[email]">
  <input class="short" type="submit" value="Submit" name="commit">
</form>
```

In my CSS file, I've set set:

```
.short{ height: 13px; }
```

I get the expected 13px height with the text input field, but the submit button's height is cropped to 7px. I checked in firebug, and the only line of CSS affecting the button's height is line 39, where I declare .short. This happens in both Chrome and Firefox. What might be causing it?

Comment: It's rendering as 13px in Chrome for me. Take a look, your input box is actually rendering at 20px because of the border and padding that is default from browsers, remove those and it is the same size as the button which is indeed 13px. http://jsfiddle.net/cCTE9/

Comment: As it turns out, I'm using an [HTML5 reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/), and I'm still getting this effect in both Firefox and Chrome, even when I explicitly set short's padding and margins to 0. I suspect there's some other interaction going on here, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: Form input elements are usually set to `box-sizing:border-box;` which means the the border and padding are included in the height.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Apparently, that was the problem. Both Firefox and Chrome were rendering a rather thick, yet invisible border around the input button. When I set border to 0, it solved the problem.